# Use jQuery to load header content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a asp.NET like master page with jQuery. Below is the code I am using but the jQuery does not load HTML from the referenced file and I get a $ is not defined in the Firefox debugger.

My Folder is setup like so:

- Folder: content
- Folder: css
- Folder: fonts
- Folder: img
- Folder: js
- File: index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- STYLESHEETS -->
  <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="/css/style-ixv0ab381.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="/css/style-main.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- FONTS -->
  <link href="/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- SCRIPTS -->
  <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/progressBar.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="header" class="container">
      <script>
        $("header").load("/content/header.html");
      </script>
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="container">

    </div>
    <div id="footer" class="container">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're probably referencing your jquery file wrong then... Where is your jquery file in reference to your html file?

Comment: Aside from the error, I'd suggest using server side includes to achieve this. Doing it in client code leads to more requests to the server and also a FOUC before the AJAX request completes.

Comment: I'm just starting in web development and I'm not sure which is which. I was trying to keep all the content which will be the same across all pages in one file and just have to change the info in the content files.

Comment: I would like to move the head info to the master file as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The path to your jQuery file is probably incorrect. If you replace it with a CDN link (like https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js), that error is not thrown anymore

Comment: Tried the CDN; the data still isnt displayed. But I don't get the Reference Error: $is not defined.

Comment: Since the jQuery path is wrong, I would guess the other paths are likely wrong also. Are all of your other CSS and JS files loading properly? Is an error thrown when you try to load the header file?

Comment: I'm not sure. In the Firefox Developer Tools - Style Editor says the page has no style sheet

Comment: In VSCode I can ctrl+click on the link and it opens file

Comment: If you go to the console inside of devtools it will throw errors if a resource fails to load

Comment: The only one it throws is "$ is not defined" for the line between the <script></script>

Comment: No. I don't. I could send you the source if you would like.

Comment: sure I'm happy to take a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138669/discussion-between-troypilewski-and-aj-funk).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that the path to jQuery is correct. You can alternatively use CDN-powered links to jQuery library which can be found at: https://code.jquery.com/

Secondly, the best practice is to include all JavaScript files before the end of  tag and not between  tags. Keep in mind that the order in which you include JavaScript files is sometimes affecting your website. Therefore, include the JavaScript files that belong to the core of your website on a top-to-bottom path.

Finally, I would recommend you to read **[Absolute vs Relative Paths/Links](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/)** article in order to understand how paths to files work.

Comment: Tried the CDN; the data still isnt displayed. But I don't get the Reference Error: $is not defined.